# When while loop placed in wxPython events

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython

I'm trying to write a GUI program grabbing specific contents from a webpage. The idea is when I hit the start button, the program should start extracting information from that page. And I want to add some code to check if connected to the Internet. If not, continue trying until connected.

So I just added the following code in the event, but found it didn't work. Also the whole program has to be closed in a forced way. Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
import time

InternetNotOn = True

while InternetNotOn:
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
        InternetNotOn = False
        print "Everyting is fine!"
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "Error!"
        time.sleep(10)
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you notice the typo in your code? Interne*r*NotOn

Comment: Sorry for the typo... just corrected it

Comment: Does "Everyting is fine!" get printed? Once? or many times?

Comment: @unutbu: If connected to the Internet, everything works fine. "Everything is fine!" get printed only once. The problem is when you are not connected to the Internet, I just want the program to check the connection every 10 seconds or so, and if connected just do the job. But the code does not work as I expected, the program freezes and you have to force the GUI program to quit. "Error" does get printed every 10 seconds in the console though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have an event based program, the overall flow of the program is this:

```
while the-program-is-running:
    wait-for-an-event
    service-the-event
exit
```

Now, lets see what happens when service-the-event calls something with a (potentially) infinite loop:

```
while the-program-is-running:
    wait-for-an-event
    while the-internet-is-on:
        do-something
exit
```

Do you see the problem? In the worse case your program may never call wait-for-an-event again because your loop is running.

Remember: the event loop is already an infinite loop, you don't need to add another infinite loop inside of it. Instead, take advantage of the existing loop. You can use [wx.CallAfter](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter) or [wx.CallLater](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html) to call a method which will cause your function to be called at the next iteration of the event loop.

Then, within your function you call [wx.CallAfter](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter) or [wx.CallLater](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html) again to cause it to again be called on the next iteration of the event loop.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `time.sleep(10)` you can call [wxApp::Yield](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxapp.html#wxappyield) and `time.sleep(1)` ten times.

Beware of reentrancy problems (e.g. pressing the start button again.). The start button could be dimmed while in the event handler.

But [Bryan Oakley's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458023/when-while-loop-placed-in-wxpython-events/3458633#3458633) is probably the better way.